# Sales report pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure that generates sales report for any given month. To invoke the procedure I can pass only one parameter that is the month to get the number of sales as well as the total sale.I joined three tables that are: orders, odetails and parts as in the select query below. My problem is the procedure I created does not generate any record when I pass the date to it! Could you please show me how to alter?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SALE_REPORT (P_DATE IN DATE ) 
   AS
V_PNO ODETAILS.PNO%TYPE;
NUMBER_SALES ODETAILS.QTY%TYPE;
TOTAL_SALE  PARTS.PRICE%TYPE;
V_SHIPPED ORDERS.SHIPPED%TYPE;
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('           REPORT          ');
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*****************************');
  FOR REC IN 
  (SELECT OD.PNO, SUM(OD.QTY) "NUMBER OF SALES", SUM(NVL(OD.QTY,0) * NVL  
                                   (P.PRICE,0)) AS TOTAL_SALE, O.SHIPPED 
  INTO V_PNO, NUMBER_SALES, TOTAL_SALE, V_SHIPPED 
  FROM ORDERS O, ODETAILS OD, PARTS P
  WHERE O.ONO = OD.ONO
  AND P.PNO = OD.PNO
  AND O.SHIPPED = TO_CHAR(P_DATE, 'DD-MON-yyyy')
  GROUP BY  O.SHIPPED, OD.PNO
  ORDER BY SUM(OD.QTY) DESC) LOOP

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SHIP DATE '||  V_PNO);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SHIP DATE '|| V_SHIPPED);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NUMBER OF SALES '|| NUMBER_SALES);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL SALES '|| TOTAL_SALE );
  EXIT WHEN SQL%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
END SALE_REPORT;
```

Comment: Is `o.shipped` a `date`?  If so, why are you comparing it to a character string?  What is the value of `p_date`?  Are all the `o.shipped` values midnight on the first of the month?  That seems unlikely.  I would guess that `o.shipped` is the actual date and time that an order shipped and that you really want all the rows that shipped at any point in the month.  You also don't use an `exit when sql%notfound` in an implicit loop.

Comment: One more thing: instead of storing each field in a variable, print them using RECORD.FIELD syntax (for example, REC.PNO).

Comment: Hi Justin, Yes, o.shipped is a date! to invoke the procedure I should pass a month to it and the procedure should display number of sales and total sales of the month i passed! Never came to my mind o.shipped is s string.

Comment: Hi Neria, I did what you said but got errors and it says: Error(23,43): PLS-00302: component 'V_PNO' must be declared, but this for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your syntax.

If you're using a `FOR` loop, you don't need `SELECT ... INTO` construct, use `REC` variable you declared - actually, I'm rather surprised that this even compiled. `EXIT WHEN SQL%NOTFOUND;` is also unnecessary as `FOR` loop automatically ends one there are no more records. Also, give columns better alias, you're going to use them as members of `REC`.

It should look like this:

```
FOR REC IN 
  (SELECT OD.PNO, SUM(OD.QTY) NUMBER_SALES, SUM(NVL(OD.QTY,0) * NVL  
                                   (P.PRICE,0)) AS TOTAL_SALE, O.SHIPPED 
  FROM ORDERS O, ODETAILS OD, PARTS P
  WHERE O.ONO = OD.ONO
  AND P.PNO = OD.PNO
  AND O.SHIPPED = TO_CHAR(P_DATE, 'DD-MON-yyyy')
  GROUP BY  O.SHIPPED, OD.PNO
  ORDER BY SUM(OD.QTY) DESC) LOOP

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SHIP DATE '||  REC.PNO);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SHIP DATE '|| REC.SHIPPED);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NUMBER OF SALES '|| REC.NUMBER_SALES);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL SALES '|| REC.TOTAL_SALE );
END LOOP;
```

I would also make this query into a cursor and move to the declaration, but that's matter of preference I guess.

Now, if this still doesn't print anything, then your query doesn't return any rows. Take it to SQL worksheet, substitute P_DATE manually and debug.

**EDIT:**

If `o.shipped` is any date within month, and you're passing a date as `01-12-2015` for example, then your query will only return for rows where `o.shipped` exactly matches your `P_DATE`, that is, first day of the month. You should either convert dates to strings containing month and year:

```
...
AND TO_CHAR(O.SHIPPED, 'mm.yyyy') = TO_CHAR(P_DATE, 'mm.yyyy')
...
```

or use [TRUNC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084) function with a second parameter `MONTH`, which will transform your dates to the first day of month.

```
...
AND TRUNC(O.SHIPPED, 'MONTH') = TRUNC(P_DATE, 'MONTH')
...
```

Comment: I altered the procedure, however, my query does't work :(. All  I am trying to do is get number of sales and  total sales of a month ex: from 01/01/2015 to 31/01/2015

Comment: Well, with `AND O.SHIPPED = TO_CHAR(P_DATE, 'DD-MON-yyyy')` you asked oracle to find exact match for your `P_DATE`, not dates in the same month. Check the updated answer, it should work if other parts of query are correct.

Comment: Much appreciated for your answers, I have done Trunc function but it always comes back with no row selected!! My aim is to get records of number of sales  and total sales for any month! The only way I know the months of sales is with orders shipping dates and the receiving dates !

Comment: Quick update, the query worked when I used AND TO_CHAR(O.SHIPPED, 'MON') = TO_CHAR(P_DATE, 'MON'). But how do I invoke the procedure from anonymous block! I mean how do I pass the date ?

Comment: To invoke the procedure use `begin SALE_REPORT(to_date('01-12-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy')); end;`, for example. Note that `AND TO_CHAR(O.SHIPPED, 'MON') = TO_CHAR(P_DATE, 'MON')` can be dangerous because it doesn't consider the year - that is, you can get records for 12.2014 if you pass 12.2015.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It worked perfectly and understand your point in this regard, therefore I altered the date to mm-yyyy to include the year and gives a precise report when I pass the date. However, Could I create cursor to run my select query? Is it going to work the same ?

Comment: Yes. Create it in `declare` section like this: `cursor my_cursor is <your query goes next>`, then use as `for rec in my_cursor loop`. You can copy the query verbatim, it will still work because `p_date` is visible from `declare` section. Alternatively, you can add a parameter to the cursor, like `cursor my_cursor(c_date date) is <your query goes next>`, except replace `p_date` with `c_date` in query and call it like `for rec in my_cursor(p_date) loop`. Consult oracle documentation for further info, they have decent explanation and examples.